# DynamoDB - put items based on a condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Appreciate your help, as I want to put an item in DynamoDB table provided a condition is true.

For e.g. I have a table with an item called as "Category" --> Now I want to put or update the attribute value of another item "Price", only if value of attribute in "Category" is something specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,
what have you tried to succeed with your problem?

Comment: Hi, I tried following boto3 docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item.         and mentioned below is the code I am trying by now its throwing syntax error.  But I am afraid I may have failed to comprehend the documentaiton...   **bold** `code`   table.put_item(Item={'Artist':"Mettalica", 'SongTitle':"Unforgiven"}, Expected={'Category':{'Value:{'S':"SuperHit"},'ComparisonOperator': "EQ", 'AttributeValueList': [{'Price':{'S':"90"}}] } } )       ---  Thanks